# Distributional assumption on repeated measures

Tags: repeated-measures, conditional-probability, skew-normal-distribution

I would like to get your opinion/feedback about the following problem:

I have repeated measures "$y$" that are repeated for each age (e.g., 30:90), and each age is repeated for each time (2000:2010).

| y | x | t |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value# | 30 | 2000 |
| value# | 31 | 2000 |
| ... | ... | .... |
| value# | 30 | 2010 |
| value# | 31 | 2010 |
| ... | ... | .... |

I noticed that - for each time -the $y$'s over ages, are distributed following a Skew Normal distribution, and this property holds for all $t$. Therefore I would write $y_x | t  \sim SN(\mu,\sigma^2,\lambda)$

I am wondering if this setting allows us to write the model also using  this setting $y_{x,t} \sim SN(\mu,\sigma^2,\lambda)$

Thanks